# How can you insert a custom symbol?

Tags: qgis, cartography, symbology

How can you use a custom symbol for either dot density or proportional symbol maps in QGIS? Is there a way to import a symbol of your own such as a drawing or image that you can create or download from somewhere else?

Comment: Can you indicate what software you are using?

Answer (score 3):

So in QGIS, you can import a symbol in the XML form. However, right now there's not really a way to store images in XML. If you have a windows computer, you can try http://www.stylusstudio.com/download...FQ3nnAodqlgAGQ
http://www.minipdf.com/scan2word/png-to-xml.html

But it's difficult for Mac users. Sorry that I can't be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using arcgis, you can go into properties/symbology tab/ and select the symbol you want to change, then click the properties button, and go to the 'type' dropdown and select 'picture marker symbol', and navigate to your selected image